# gap.boxplot produces different figure than boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

Why does the following code produce different figures? (required package: plotrix)

```
boxplot(mpg~cyl, data =mtcars)
gap.boxplot(mpg~cyl, data =mtcars)
```

But the following code produces the same figures?

```
boxplot(mtcars$mpg)
gap.boxplot(mtcars$mpg)
```

My end goal is to produce a boxplot that has whiskers that represent 5% and 95% quantiles and able to add a gap to show extreme values. I know how to edit boxplot.default to get 5% and 95% Whiskers but I can not get my figure to agree with my data when using `gap.boxplot`. Any tips will help since I am new to R. Thank you.

Edit: The code below also produces the same figure so this leads me to believe it has something to do with how the data is arranged

```
twovec<-list(vec1=c(rnorm(30),-6),vec2=c(sample(1:10,40,TRUE),20))
boxplot(twovec)
gap.boxplot(twovec)
```

Edit2: gap.boxplot does not work when the number of "groups" is different than the number of "outputs". This is because gap.boxplot figures out the groups (`bxgap$group <- at`) different than boxplot.default. So it ends up assigning the outliers to the incorrect groups. I am still not sure how to fix this so any help would be appreciated. If I figure this out I will either post it as a solution or delete this post.

```
> summary(boxplot(mpg~cyl, data =mtcars))
  Length Class  Mode
```

stats 15     -none- numeric
n      3     -none- numeric
conf   6     -none- numeric
out    2     -none- numeric
group  2     -none- numeric
names  3     -none- character

```
> summary(gap.boxplot(mpg~cyl, data =mtcars))
  Length Class  Mode
```

stats 15     -none- numeric
n      3     -none- numeric
conf   6     -none- numeric
out    2     -none- numeric
group  3     -none- numeric
names  3     -none- character

Comment: What is `gap.boxplot`? What package is is from? It's not built in to the default packages.

Comment: Sorry it is from the package plotrix